# Passing an object class as parameter to Wordpress function

Tags: wordpress

I have to pass function `$MyClass->MyStyle` as parameter to `add_action()` but don't know how to do it. I have tried:

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', $MyClass->MyStyle );
add_action( 'admin_menu', " . $MyClass->MyStyle . " );
add_action( 'admin_menu', "$MyClass->MyStyle" );
?>
```

but none works.

What is the right syntax to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might have to declare `global $MyClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $MyClass,
                                 'MyStyle' ) ); // Register Admin Style
```

UPDATED:

I was checking the documentation for the syntax and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) it is:

"The function must be referenced in one of two ways:
if the function is a member of a class within the plugin it should be referenced as `array( $this, 'function_name' )`

if the class is instantiated as an object or array( **CLASS**, 'function_name' ) if its called statically.

In all other cases, using the function name itself is sufficient